# ¿Cómo saber si un objeto es un nodo?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo, por ejemplo, este código:

```
var nodo = document.createElement("div");
var dict = {};
var list = [];

console.log(typeof(nodo));
console.log(typeof(dict));
console.log(typeof(list));
```

La consola imprimiría esto:

> object
> object
> object

Pero, necesito una manera de comprobar cuál de todos los objetos **es un elemento html** así no esté adjunto a ningún padre, en este caso la variable que cumple esto es `nodo`. Así pues, ¿cómo sé qué objeto es un nodo, y qué objeto no lo es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si empleas la función toString() podrás percatarte que te indica el tipo de objeto que es cada uno. Ahora para diferenciarlo puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
function isNode(obj){
  return obj.toString().indexOf(' HTML')>0;
}

var div = document.createElement("div");
var obj = {};

alert(isNode(div));

alert(isNode(obj));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahi te puse 2 ejemplos para que vieras el resultado de llamar a la misma función pero pasandole diferentes objetos

Comment: Gracias. Yo pensaba que las conversiones a cadenas `"[object *]"` eran por el navegador, pero ahora veo que es del mismo JavaScript.